# Какой слушатель есть для comboBox в python?

Tags: python

Какой слушатель можно повесить на comboBox в QtWidgets.QMainWindow, чтобы отслеживать изменения в combox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def on_change(i):
    print(comboBox.currentText())


comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(on_change)
```

Comment: self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged().connect(self.click())
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable  - Пишет ошибку. Хотя вроде всё подключено from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

Comment: @chilo5432 потому что надо ссылку на метод передавать, а на результат его вызова.

Comment: Всё равно ошибка: self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged(0).connect(self.cell_changed)
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable

Comment: @chilo5432 исправил ответ, проверьте.